# R - lme4 - nlopt-2.4.2 fails to install

Tags: r, linux

I am having problems to install the package lme4 in R.
Following the output. It looks like it can't open nlopt. Someone knows how to solve it?
I am in Linux 16.10

```
checking nlopt.h usability... no
checking nlopt.h presence... no
checking for nlopt.h... no
configure: Need to download and build NLopt
trying URL 'http://ab-initio.mit.edu/nlopt/nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz'
Error in download.file(url = "http://ab-initio.mit.edu/nlopt/nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz",  : 
  cannot open URL 'http://ab-initio.mit.edu/nlopt/nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz'
Execution halted
/bin/tar: This does not look like a tar archive

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
/bin/tar: Child returned status 1
/bin/tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Warning message:
In untar(tarfile = "nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz") :
  '/bin/tar -xf 'nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz'' returned error code 2
configure: Starting to install library to /tmp/Rtmp1o9ETL/R.INSTALL2a78412beb2/nloptr/nlopt-2.4.2
./configure: line 3325: cd: nlopt-2.4.2: No such file or directory
```

Comment: The download worked for me just now. Perhaps the server was temporarily unavailable. Have you tried again?

Comment: There is no need to build nlopt from source.  I helped Jelmer a while back to use `libnlopt-dev` if installed.  _Much faster_ installation.

Comment: Yes, I have tried 2 servers actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Briefly:

- There is no such thing as "Linux 16.10'
- There is Ubuntu 16.10
- [Optional] On Ubuntu, see [this README from CRAN](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) on how to get R and some packages prebuilt from CRAN
- Irregardless, and answered here before `checking for nlopt.h... no` is the hint: do `sudo apt-get install libnlopt-dev` and try again.
- You can get both `r-cran-nloptr` and `r-cran-lme4` from Ubuntu too but those may be older versions given that your OS is 16.04, ie from 2016.